# remove duplicates in java

Tags: java, file, arraylist, duplicates

Write a program that reads a file of numbers of type int and writes all the numbers to another file, but without any duplicate numbers.
Assume that the numbers in the input file are already ordered from smallest to largest. After the program is run, the new file will contain all the numbers in the original file, but no number will appear more than once in the file. The numbers in the output file should also be sorted from smallest to largest. Your program should obtain both file names from the user

```
 Scanner data;       
    PrintWriter result; 

    ArrayList<Integer> numbers;  
    numbers = new ArrayList<>();

    try {  
        data = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\data.txt"));
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Can't find file data.txt!");
        return;  
    }

    try {  
        result = new PrintWriter("C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\result.txt");
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Can't open file result.txt!");
        System.out.println("Error: " + e);
        data.close(); 
        return;        
    }

    while ( data.hasNextInt()) {  
        int inputNumber = data.nextInt();
        numbers.add(inputNumber);
        
    }

  

    for (int i = numbers.size()-1; i >= 0; i--)
        result.println(numbers.get(i));
          

    System.out.println("Done!");

    data.close();
    result.close();

}
```

Comment: You stated the assignment but asked no question.

Comment: What would you do by hand? Repeatedly: read a number, if it is not the same as the previous number, write it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [SortedSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) instead of the arraylist to get a sorted list of numbers without any duplicates.

Or if you still want to use ArrayList you can read, ignore duplicates and write in a single loop.

```java
...
    while(data.hasNextInt()) {  
        int inputNumber = data.nextInt();
        if(!numbers.contains(inputNumber)) { 
             numbers.add(inputNumber);
             result.println(inputNumber);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Done!");

    data.close();
    result.close();
 
}
```

Or another faster way (only works if input list is sorted)

```java
    // save the previous number
    int prev = -999999;
    while(data.hasNextInt()) {  
        int inputNumber = data.nextInt();
        if(inputNumber != prev) { 
             prev = inputNumber
             result.println(inputNumber);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Done!");

    data.close();
    result.close();

}
```